# Tricks for saving battery life

Tags: windows-phone-7, locking, windows-phone-7.1, power-management

I want to use accelerometer in my app when the user sleep. When WP7 is locked then accelerometer is turned off so I must set `UserIdleDetectionMode` to disable and then I disable lock screen but now the phone woudn´t be saving battery so what I must do for saving battery, for doing fake lock screen?

Comment: Whats the relation between user sleeping and using accelerometer?

Comment: I want to create alarm and awake user when he is in REM sleep.

Comment: Why do you need the accelerometer for that? Phones have alarms. (But if your app woke me from a REM sleep, it would be gone from my phone about 2 seconds later.)

Comment: I am not sure if I was right with REM but there are alarms which awake you in right moment. In the moment when you sleep least and you woke up very quickly and ready. These alarms find out when they shoudl wake up accord to your movements. When you are move very much it´s the best moment. So this is why I need accelerometer.

Answer (score 0):

The other apps I've seen which do this recommend that the user plug their device in while using it.
I don't think this is an unreasonable solution as it's safe to assume that most users will charge their phones over night anyway. (Due to current battery technologies and the power consumption of the phones.)